# Facebook 4.3.0, shareDialog does not opening in Android

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I have integrated Facebook sdk to my project and below is the code for opening shareDialog box to share text with Image

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
   ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("file://"+saveCanvasImage()))
                .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .build();

 shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

in AndroidMenifest.xml file code is below

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider863551910397594"
        android:exported="true" />
```

I have also provided Key Hashes in

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

When ever I execute above code I will get below logs in LOGCAT

```
07-03 11:33:29.352: I/ActivityManager(756): START u0 {act=PassThrough cmp=com.drcsystems.emoji/com.facebook.FacebookActivity (has extras)} from uid 10512 on display 0
07-03 11:33:29.355: V/WindowManager(756): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{228e0639 token=Token{3b676e00 ActivityRecord{1c400c83 u0 com.drcsystems.emoji/com.facebook.FacebookActivity t5409}}} to stack=1 task=5409 at 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code for open facebook dialog in your activity:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this).setName("name").
setLink("Website").setDescription("description").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding callbacks I got that

```
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("file://"+saveCanvasImage()))
```

**requires http:// or https://**

Means above code should be

```
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://....."))
```

means you can not share directly from sdcard you need to first upload on any server then you can share with it